# Access an array of objects in a class method in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have been learning Java recently. I had a doubt and I am not sure if this is even possible to implement.

Suppose I have a class GameBoard and I create an array of objects,

```
GameBoard[][] board = new GameBoard[4][4];
```

Now if I need to call a non-static method of the class GameBoard, is it possible to call it as,

```
board.clear(); //clear the squares on the game board
```

or do I need to call the elements individually?

```
board[1][1].clear();
board[2][2].clear();
```

If it is possible to call board.clear(), is there a way to loop through the elements of the array to clear them inside the clear() method?

Comment: *"If it is possible to call board.clear()"*  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: You cannot call methods on an array directly (except for the methods in class `Object`). You must iterate through the array using nested `for` loops and call `clear()` on each one.

Comment: trry this thing on your own ... then ask why that happened ...rather what will happen

Comment: @AndrewThompson yeah sorry about that. As I was writing the line board.clear(), it stuck me as odd. Probably should test them, get an error then post.

Comment: It's the usual way to go: try first, fail try again, fail again, think, ... and post eventually.
People will be here to help after you tried :)

Comment: It's a good idea to test, but no big deal..  Your intent was pretty clear from the words.  :)

Comment: Your problem is mixing metaphors -- If you have a game, it might be `Square[][]` inside a Gameboard object, but you wouldn't (except in multidimensional chess, perhaps) have `Gameboard[][]`.  Your Gameboard might contain `Square[][] squares`, and then `gameboard.clear()` might translate into a double loop calling `squares[x][y].clear()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll have to clear all of them individually. Your array is just a container for many objects references that you have to access one at a time.

Hopefully, Object Oriented programming allows you to define a `clear()` method that can do that for you.

Wait for Java 8 and lambdas ;)

Answer (score 2):

`board` is declared as array, not object of `GameBoard`

So it contains object of `GameBoard`

when you do this `board` it is an array.
when you do `board[0][0]` this, type is `GameBoard`, so you can only call by accessing cells of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing a 2-dimensional array of `GameBoard` instances, 16 in total, with the following line:

```
GameBoard[][] board = new GameBoard[4][4];
```

This `board` array of arrays will contain `null` values for all elements, until you initialize them, e.g.:

```
board[0][0] = new GameBoard();
```

Or, in a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        board[i][j] = new GameBoard();
    }
}
```

You're right that you can't call `clear()` on `board` directly, `clear()` is not something you can call on an array. You'd want to call `board[i][j].clear()` or in a similar loop (but only after you've initialized them, or you'll try to call something on `null`, and get a `NullPointerException`).

Comment: Ha thanks Matthieu, I just approved your edit of my code while reviewing the review queue (lol I stumbled on my own answer)!

Comment: Hehe no problem, I'm a typo freak :) I had to add a couple extra () to match the 6-char limit though ;)

Answer (score 0):

board is an array of Object gameBoard. you need to first qualify array and then can use static refrence